# Did I place the right minions?

Tags: stuffed-fables

In the setup for Big Girl Bed opening page, you are told not to put any leader cards in your deck.  However, you are then told to place a crawly per stuffie, which in a 4 player game is 4.  There were 4 shapes, but one was the leader shape, so I put it out there but used the non-leader stats.  Was that right?  If not, what did I miss as far as placing them?

Since we are past it, I am mostly asking in case this happens again.  I am guessing the leaderless scenario will be rare, if it ever happens again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be confusing **Leader** cards with **Boss** cards.
The rules do not say anything about leaving out Leaders; they only say that during the setup of the first scenario you won't have any Bosses (which is true; they show up as the game progresses).

Comment: Ah you're right.  I have not encountered any scenarios where I would have bosses in a face up pile so I made that confusion.  So I guess the right behavior would have been 3 normal and 1 leader, I made it easy on us.  Thanks!